# Make 'enter'-key run a function from an input type="text"

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm having a small problem here.

I have a textfield (not area) and I want a JS function to be run when I press enter. This is instead of having a separate 'submit' button. 
Right now I'm trying to use the 'onKeyPress' event, but that runs the function every time I type one letter in. So if I want to write 'LIKE', it posts 'L' then 'LI' then 'LIK' and then 'LIKE'. It reacts every time I press anything, not only when I enter.

I do not have a form, just a simple input type="text":

```
<input type="text" id="' + post_id + '" onKeyPress="fbComment(\''+post_id+'\')"> Post a comment </input>
```

If some of you remember my last question, this will be a part of my facebook_footer variable (I'm trying out the FB API), and the finished thing looks like this:

```
var facebook_footer = '<button onClick="fbLike(\''+post_id+'\')"> Like </button> <input type="text" id="' + post_id + '" onKeyPress="fbComment(\''+post_id+'\')"> Post a comment </input>';
```

Do any of you know what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

heres a simple function -

```
textElement.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        alert('you press enter')
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I have to check for which key was pressed then? There is no function for when the text-field is like "submitted"? Like I press enter on Google, and then they check which key was pressed?

Comment: There is an `onsubmit` event but yes Google,facebook, etc heavily make use of the keypress event to determine the ENTER key event and used it for submitting query to the server!

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the enter key within the input:

```
$("#inputIDHERE").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Comment: So, I have to check for which key was pressed then? There is no function for when the text-field is like "submitted"?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that - you'll just need some extra logic in your javascript.

Check out [Keyboard Events Tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events)

You just have to peek into the keypress event to see what key was entered. The event object has a keycode or which property that will have a value to correspond to the key pressed, and keycode 13 is the enter/return button.

Additional reference: [Javascript Character Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
$("#inputIDHERE").bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

I also added <form></form> around my input tag, though that may not be necessary.